# Migration from XCode3 to 4 Issue with Build

Tags: xcode4

Have a existing project on XCode 3 and since it could not simulate iOS5 decided to move to XCode 4. Installed Xcode 4 and to do that i had to upgrade to Mac OS 10.6.8
Imported the existing project to Xcode 4 and i have issues with the build

Following is the  error i get :

error: remove /Users/UK/Downloads/XYZ/DerivedData/XYZ/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XYZ.app/XYZ.app: Directory not empty

I have tried the following options :

1. From the Organizer in XCode 4 tried to clean the Derived Data by deleting it.
2. Gone to the folder where Derived Data is and deleted it physically.

I still get the same build issue.